# Which Registry Editor Version to initiate reg file with when editing the Windows registry (if needed at all)?

Tags: windows, batch-file, windows-7, registry

According to [Microsoft knowledge base article 310516](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/310516), one should initiate .reg files editing the Windows registry with either

- `Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00`
  for Windows 2000, Windows XP, and Windows Server 2003
  **or**
- `REGEDIT4`
  for Windows 95, Windows 98 and Windows NT 4.0.

When on Windows 7, is it correct to initiate with `Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00` or should one state version 6 instead?

Is it in fact needed at all when running a .bat file instead?

For current version click in *Registry Editor* in menu **Help** on menu item **About Registry Editor**.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are used mainly two standard applications to process Windows registry from within a batch file:

- **reg.exe**
- **regedit.exe**

On Windows x64 both exist as 32-bit and as 64-bit applications whereby the 32-bit versions access the registry like 32-bit applications which means [registry redirector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winprog64/registry-redirector) is active and registry keys for 64-bit applications are not visible for 32-bit **REG** and **REGEDIT**.

It is in general better to use **REG** instead of **REGEDIT** for getting (read access) or setting (write access) just a few keys or values in batch files.

The usage of **REGEDIT** requires always administrator privileges since Windows Vista even when just used to export keys into a registry file (read access) or when importing data from a registry file (write access) to **HKEY_CURRENT_USER** (short: HKCU).

By using **REG** many operations like **QUERY** (read access) or **ADD** (write access) to HKCU don't need administrator privileges. Of course a write access to **HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE** (short: HKLM) requires administrator privileges as also other not often used operations. Running in a command prompt window `reg /?` shows the available operations. `reg query /?` and `reg add /?` executed in a console window displays syntax and options to get (query) or set (add) data in Windows registry.

A *.reg file is interpreted on import only as file with valid registry data if the first line of the file contains

- **REGEDIT4**
  or
- **Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00**

This is not the version of registry editor or the Windows version. It is a version information for format of the registry data in the file itself. So it is a registry file format version. The first line of a registry file **must** have one of those two strings.

**An attempt importing a *.reg file without this header line results in an error.**

Windows 2000 (has also *regedt32.exe*) and later versions of Windows support registry files in both format versions, 4 and 5.

Windows 95, 98, Millennium and NT4 support only registry files in format 4.

**So it depends nowadays (year 2016) mainly on the data which format to use for a registry file.**

**The main difference is the supported [encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_encoding) of text data.**

Registry files in format *REGEDIT4* can be only text files with 1 byte per character using the [code page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page) defined in Windows [Locales and Languages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/intl/locales-and-languages) settings for non Unicode aware applications which is [Windows-1252](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_1252) for North American and Western European countries. Therefore registry files in format *REGEDIT4* cannot contain [Unicode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode) characters with a code value greater 255 (decimal, 0xFF hexadecimal).

Registry files in format *Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00* support text encoded with more than 1 byte per character according to [Unicode](http://www.unicode.org/) standard. Therefore *.reg files in format *Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00* are created by **REGEDIT** as [UTF-16](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16) [Little Endian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) encoded text files with [Byte Order Mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_Order_Mark) (FF FE).

So it does not matter which file format to use if the data to import / export is binary or text using only [ASCII](http://www.asciitable.com/) characters (code value < decimal 128) as 99.99 % of all registry data.

For non ASCII characters it is already important to know which code page is used by Windows command interpreter as this is usually an OEM code page like [code page 437](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_437) (US, Canada) or [code page 850](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_850) (Western Europe) being different from GUI code page Windows-1252. Running in a command prompt window `chcp` or `mode con` outputs the default code page used on current computer by Windows command interpreter for console.

If it is really necessary to support also Unicode strings, it is necessary to use format *Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00*.

Let us look on a hypothetical Unicode example:

In Windows registry under key `HKCU\RegFormat` there are two Unicode strings defined:

- A string of type `REG_SZ` with name `Two Not Equal 3` with Unicode string value:

  `2 ≠ 3`
- A multi-line string of type `REG_MULTI_SZ` with name `Formulas` with Unicode string value:

  `2 µs × 3 = 6 µs`
  `A = π × r²`

See the Microsoft articles [Registry Value Types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sysinfo/registry-value-types), [Distributing Registry Changes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-2000-server/bb727154(v=technet.10)) and [Data Types in the Registry](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2003/cc785172(v=ws.10)) for details about registry value types.

Exporting key `HKCU\RegFormat` in format *Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00* being the standard format since Windows 2000 results in a UTF-16 LE encoded text file with 596 bytes with content:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\RegFormat]
"Two Not Equal 3"="2 ≠ 3"
"Formulas"=hex(7):32,00,20,00,b5,00,73,00,20,00,d7,00,20,00,33,00,20,00,3d,00,\
  20,00,36,00,20,00,b5,00,73,00,00,00,41,00,20,00,3d,00,20,00,c0,03,20,00,d7,\
  00,20,00,72,00,b2,00,00,00,00,00
```

The byte stream of this file is displayed in a hexadecimal viewer/editor as:

```
00000000h: FF FE 57 00 69 00 6E 00 64 00 6F 00 77 00 73 00 ; ÿþW.i.n.d.o.w.s.
00000010h: 20 00 52 00 65 00 67 00 69 00 73 00 74 00 72 00 ;  .R.e.g.i.s.t.r.
00000020h: 79 00 20 00 45 00 64 00 69 00 74 00 6F 00 72 00 ; y. .E.d.i.t.o.r.
00000030h: 20 00 56 00 65 00 72 00 73 00 69 00 6F 00 6E 00 ;  .V.e.r.s.i.o.n.
00000040h: 20 00 35 00 2E 00 30 00 30 00 0D 00 0A 00 0D 00 ;  .5...0.0.......
00000050h: 0A 00 5B 00 48 00 4B 00 45 00 59 00 5F 00 43 00 ; ..[.H.K.E.Y._.C.
00000060h: 55 00 52 00 52 00 45 00 4E 00 54 00 5F 00 55 00 ; U.R.R.E.N.T._.U.
00000070h: 53 00 45 00 52 00 5C 00 52 00 65 00 67 00 46 00 ; S.E.R.\.R.e.g.F.
00000080h: 6F 00 72 00 6D 00 61 00 74 00 5D 00 0D 00 0A 00 ; o.r.m.a.t.].....
00000090h: 22 00 54 00 77 00 6F 00 20 00 4E 00 6F 00 74 00 ; ".T.w.o. .N.o.t.
000000a0h: 20 00 45 00 71 00 75 00 61 00 6C 00 20 00 33 00 ;  .E.q.u.a.l. .3.
000000b0h: 22 00 3D 00 22 00 32 00 20 00 60 22 20 00 33 00 ; ".=.".2. .`" .3.
000000c0h: 22 00 0D 00 0A 00 22 00 46 00 6F 00 72 00 6D 00 ; ".....".F.o.r.m.
000000d0h: 75 00 6C 00 61 00 73 00 22 00 3D 00 68 00 65 00 ; u.l.a.s.".=.h.e.
000000e0h: 78 00 28 00 37 00 29 00 3A 00 33 00 32 00 2C 00 ; x.(.7.).:.3.2.,.
000000f0h: 30 00 30 00 2C 00 32 00 30 00 2C 00 30 00 30 00 ; 0.0.,.2.0.,.0.0.
00000100h: 2C 00 62 00 35 00 2C 00 30 00 30 00 2C 00 37 00 ; ,.b.5.,.0.0.,.7.
00000110h: 33 00 2C 00 30 00 30 00 2C 00 32 00 30 00 2C 00 ; 3.,.0.0.,.2.0.,.
00000120h: 30 00 30 00 2C 00 64 00 37 00 2C 00 30 00 30 00 ; 0.0.,.d.7.,.0.0.
00000130h: 2C 00 32 00 30 00 2C 00 30 00 30 00 2C 00 33 00 ; ,.2.0.,.0.0.,.3.
00000140h: 33 00 2C 00 30 00 30 00 2C 00 32 00 30 00 2C 00 ; 3.,.0.0.,.2.0.,.
00000150h: 30 00 30 00 2C 00 33 00 64 00 2C 00 30 00 30 00 ; 0.0.,.3.d.,.0.0.
00000160h: 2C 00 5C 00 0D 00 0A 00 20 00 20 00 32 00 30 00 ; ,.\..... . .2.0.
00000170h: 2C 00 30 00 30 00 2C 00 33 00 36 00 2C 00 30 00 ; ,.0.0.,.3.6.,.0.
00000180h: 30 00 2C 00 32 00 30 00 2C 00 30 00 30 00 2C 00 ; 0.,.2.0.,.0.0.,.
00000190h: 62 00 35 00 2C 00 30 00 30 00 2C 00 37 00 33 00 ; b.5.,.0.0.,.7.3.
000001a0h: 2C 00 30 00 30 00 2C 00 30 00 30 00 2C 00 30 00 ; ,.0.0.,.0.0.,.0.
000001b0h: 30 00 2C 00 34 00 31 00 2C 00 30 00 30 00 2C 00 ; 0.,.4.1.,.0.0.,.
000001c0h: 32 00 30 00 2C 00 30 00 30 00 2C 00 33 00 64 00 ; 2.0.,.0.0.,.3.d.
000001d0h: 2C 00 30 00 30 00 2C 00 32 00 30 00 2C 00 30 00 ; ,.0.0.,.2.0.,.0.
000001e0h: 30 00 2C 00 63 00 30 00 2C 00 30 00 33 00 2C 00 ; 0.,.c.0.,.0.3.,.
000001f0h: 32 00 30 00 2C 00 30 00 30 00 2C 00 64 00 37 00 ; 2.0.,.0.0.,.d.7.
00000200h: 2C 00 5C 00 0D 00 0A 00 20 00 20 00 30 00 30 00 ; ,.\..... . .0.0.
00000210h: 2C 00 32 00 30 00 2C 00 30 00 30 00 2C 00 37 00 ; ,.2.0.,.0.0.,.7.
00000220h: 32 00 2C 00 30 00 30 00 2C 00 62 00 32 00 2C 00 ; 2.,.0.0.,.b.2.,.
00000230h: 30 00 30 00 2C 00 30 00 30 00 2C 00 30 00 30 00 ; 0.0.,.0.0.,.0.0.
00000240h: 2C 00 30 00 30 00 2C 00 30 00 30 00 0D 00 0A 00 ; ,.0.0.,.0.0.....
00000250h: 0D 00 0A 00                                     ; ....
```

The first 2 bytes being displayed with code page Windows-1252 as `ÿþ` are the two bytes of the UTF-16 LE BOM which is not displayed by text editors in text editing mode.

But exporting key `HKCU\RegFormat` in format *REGEDIT4* by clicking on *file type* drop down list in export dialog and selecting **Win9x/NT4 registry files** results in an ANSI (more precise: Windows-1252) encoded text file with just 180 bytes with content:

```
REGEDIT4

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\RegFormat]
"Two Not Equal 3"="2 ? 3"
"Formulas"=hex(7):32,20,b5,73,20,d7,20,33,20,3d,20,36,20,b5,73,00,41,20,3d,20,\
  c0,20,d7,20,72,b2,00,00
```

The byte stream of this file is displayed in a hexadecimal viewer/editor as:

```
00000000h: 52 45 47 45 44 49 54 34 0D 0A 0D 0A 5B 48 4B 45 ; REGEDIT4....[HKE
00000010h: 59 5F 43 55 52 52 45 4E 54 5F 55 53 45 52 5C 52 ; Y_CURRENT_USER\R
00000020h: 65 67 46 6F 72 6D 61 74 5D 0D 0A 22 54 77 6F 20 ; egFormat].."Two 
00000030h: 4E 6F 74 20 45 71 75 61 6C 20 33 22 3D 22 32 20 ; Not Equal 3"="2 
00000040h: 3F 20 33 22 0D 0A 22 46 6F 72 6D 75 6C 61 73 22 ; ? 3".."Formulas"
00000050h: 3D 68 65 78 28 37 29 3A 33 32 2C 32 30 2C 62 35 ; =hex(7):32,20,b5
00000060h: 2C 37 33 2C 32 30 2C 64 37 2C 32 30 2C 33 33 2C ; ,73,20,d7,20,33,
00000070h: 32 30 2C 33 64 2C 32 30 2C 33 36 2C 32 30 2C 62 ; 20,3d,20,36,20,b
00000080h: 35 2C 37 33 2C 30 30 2C 34 31 2C 32 30 2C 33 64 ; 5,73,00,41,20,3d
00000090h: 2C 32 30 2C 5C 0D 0A 20 20 63 30 2C 32 30 2C 64 ; ,20,\..  c0,20,d
000000a0h: 37 2C 32 30 2C 37 32 2C 62 32 2C 30 30 2C 30 30 ; 7,20,72,b2,00,00
000000b0h: 0D 0A 0D 0A                                     ; ....
```

What are the differences?

1. **REGEDIT** first converted the string of type REG_SZ from Unicode to code page Windows-1252 and then exported the data. The result is character `?` instead of [not equal sign](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2260/index.htm) with Unicode value U+2260 in string of type `REG_SZ` because this character is not available in code page Windows-1252.
2. The multi-line string has just halve of the hexadecimal values (just 1 byte per character instead of 2 bytes per character).
3. The [small PI](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/03c0/index.htm) with Unicode value U+03C0 is stored with value C0 (just low byte) and is therefore now the character `À` as this character has code value 0xC0 in code page Windows-1252.

Importing the data from file in format *Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00* results in getting same data in Windows registry as before.

But importing the data from file in format *REGEDIT4* results in:

- A string of type `REG_SZ` with name `Two Not Equal 3` with ANSI string value:

  `2 ? 3`
- A multi-line string of type `REG_MULTI_SZ` with name `Formulas` with Unicode string value:

  `2 µs × 3 = 6 µs`
  `A = À × r²`

The characters `µ` and `×` and `²` have a code value < 255 (decimal) and can be therefore correct stored also in registry file of format *REGEDIT4*. But `≠` and `π` can't be correct encoded in format 4.

A registry file of format *Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00* must not be itself a Unicode encoded text file. It is also possible to have a Windows-1252 encoded registry file with content:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\RegFormat]
"Two Not Equal 3"=hex(1):32,00,60,22,33,00
"Formulas"=hex(7):32,00,20,00,b5,00,73,00,20,00,d7,00,20,00,33,00,20,00,3d,00,\
  20,00,36,00,20,00,b5,00,73,00,00,00,41,00,20,00,3d,00,20,00,c0,03,20,00,d7,\
  00,20,00,72,00,b2,00,00,00,00,00
```

being displayed in a hexadecimal viewer/editor as:

```
00000000h: 57 69 6E 64 6F 77 73 20 52 65 67 69 73 74 72 79 ; Windows Registry
00000010h: 20 45 64 69 74 6F 72 20 56 65 72 73 69 6F 6E 20 ;  Editor Version 
00000020h: 35 2E 30 30 0D 0A 0D 0A 5B 48 4B 45 59 5F 43 55 ; 5.00....[HKEY_CU
00000030h: 52 52 45 4E 54 5F 55 53 45 52 5C 52 65 67 46 6F ; RRENT_USER\RegFo
00000040h: 72 6D 61 74 5D 0D 0A 22 54 77 6F 20 4E 6F 74 20 ; rmat].."Two Not 
00000050h: 45 71 75 61 6C 20 33 22 3D 68 65 78 28 31 29 3A ; Equal 3"=hex(1):
00000060h: 33 32 2C 30 30 2C 36 30 2C 32 32 2C 33 33 2C 30 ; 32,00,60,22,33,0
00000070h: 30 0D 0A 22 46 6F 72 6D 75 6C 61 73 22 3D 68 65 ; 0.."Formulas"=he
00000080h: 78 28 37 29 3A 33 32 2C 30 30 2C 32 30 2C 30 30 ; x(7):32,00,20,00
00000090h: 2C 62 35 2C 30 30 2C 37 33 2C 30 30 2C 32 30 2C ; ,b5,00,73,00,20,
000000a0h: 30 30 2C 64 37 2C 30 30 2C 32 30 2C 30 30 2C 33 ; 00,d7,00,20,00,3
000000b0h: 33 2C 30 30 2C 32 30 2C 30 30 2C 33 64 2C 30 30 ; 3,00,20,00,3d,00
000000c0h: 2C 5C 0D 0A 20 20 32 30 2C 30 30 2C 33 36 2C 30 ; ,\..  20,00,36,0
000000d0h: 30 2C 32 30 2C 30 30 2C 62 35 2C 30 30 2C 37 33 ; 0,20,00,b5,00,73
000000e0h: 2C 30 30 2C 30 30 2C 30 30 2C 34 31 2C 30 30 2C ; ,00,00,00,41,00,
000000f0h: 32 30 2C 30 30 2C 33 64 2C 30 30 2C 32 30 2C 30 ; 20,00,3d,00,20,0
00000100h: 30 2C 63 30 2C 30 33 2C 32 30 2C 30 30 2C 64 37 ; 0,c0,03,20,00,d7
00000110h: 2C 5C 0D 0A 20 20 30 30 2C 32 30 2C 30 30 2C 37 ; ,\..  00,20,00,7
00000120h: 32 2C 30 30 2C 62 32 2C 30 30 2C 30 30 2C 30 30 ; 2,00,b2,00,00,00
00000130h: 2C 30 30 2C 30 30 0D 0A 0D 0A                   ; ,00,00....
```

Importing this registry file produces nevertheless in Windows registry the Unicode strings:

```
2 ≠ 3
2 µs × 3 = 6 µs
A = À × r²
```

Using binary representation `hex(1)` for a value of type `REG_SZ` is not standard. This example was created manually by me to demonstrate that it is possible to import a Unicode string of type `REG_SZ` also with a non Unicode encoded registry file which is easier to produce from within a batch file.

But if the **name** of a key or value contains itself a Unicode character with a code value greater U+00FF, it is really necessary to use registry file format *Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00* with registry file being also Unicode encoded using 16-bit Unicode Transformation Format with little-endian format.

See function [SHRegWriteUSValue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shlwapi/nf-shlwapi-shregwriteusvaluea) for **hex**(**?**) ... **REG**_**?** registry type table.

By the way: I wrote once the UltraEdit script [GetStringFromRegHex.js](http://forums.ultraedit.com/viewtopic.php?f=52&t=16312) to get the hexadecimal values of type `hex(2)` ... `REG_EXPAND_SZ` and `hex(7)` ... `REG_MULTI_SZ` selected in a registry file opened in text editor UltraEdit displayed as text because the hexadecimal values are really hard to "read as text" for a human.

The command line

```
%SystemRoot%\System32\regedit.exe /a /e "%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\EntireWindowsRegistry.reg"
```

exports the entire Windows registry to Windows desktop in ANSI using registry file format 4.

The same command line without option `/a` results in an export of entire Windows registry in Unicode using registry file format 5.